# how to know the rules which are using a particular attribute

Tags: drools, rules, rule-engine

Say I have a rule file like below. Below rules are built on 2 properties Instrument and maverickModelMappingId. Can Drools tell me how many rules use the field "Instrument"?  My use case is that I want to know if I am deleting an attribute or a field, how many rules and which rules are going to be affected.

```
package abc.modelMapping.ruleEngine;

dialect "java"
declare FRONTOFFICESYSTEM        
Instrument : String       
maverickModelMappingId : String
end

rule "rule_MurexCredit_Rule_3"        
salience 3        
no-loop true
when

   $frontOfficeSystem : FRONTOFFICESYSTEM("Default swap".equalsIgnoreCase(Instrument))

then

   $frontOfficeSystem.setMaverickModelMappingId("001282");    
   System.out.println("001282 "+"MurexCredit_Rule_3+"); 
end     



rule "rule_MurexCredit_Rule_2"
salience 2
no-loop true
when
   $frontOfficeSystem : FRONTOFFICESYSTEM("Euro credit index option".equalsIgnoreCase(Instrument))
then
   $frontOfficeSystem.setMaverickModelMappingId("001283");
   System.out.println("001283 "+"MurexCredit_Rule_2+");
end

rule "rule_MurexCredit_Rule_1"
salience 1
no-loop true
when
   $frontOfficeSystem : FRONTOFFICESYSTEM("Credit index".equalsIgnoreCase(Instrument))
then
   $frontOfficeSystem.setMaverickModelMappingId("001282");
   System.out.println("001282 "+"MurexCredit_Rule_1+");
end
```

Comment: Drools itself doesn't have a way to tell how many rules use a property. Using your IDE's search tools would be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with Drools, as of the current version (7.33.0.Final). As mentioned in the comments, the better solution will be to use your IDE's search tools -- or other find/grep solution -- to search the text of the rule file(s) for references to the given attribute or method.